# Master theorem: When a $f(n)$ is smaller or larger than $n^{\log_b a}$by less than a polynomial factor

Tags: asymptotics, master-theorem

I was trying to solve the following question while reviewing [master theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/master-theorem/).

Which of the following asymptotically grows faster.

(a) $ T(n) = 4T(n/2) + 10n $

(b) $ T(n) = 8T(n/3) + 24n^2 $

(c) $ T(n) = 16T(n/4) + 10n^2 $

(d) $ T(n) = 25T(n/5) + 20(n\log n)^{1.99} $

(e) They are all asymptotically the same

My calculation says, (a) is $\theta(n^2)$ (b) is $\theta(n^2)$ (c) is $\theta(n^2\log n)$. Now how can I evaluate (d)?

If $f(n)$ is smaller or larger than $n^{\log_b a}$by less than a polynomial factor, how can I solve $T(n)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $ T(n) = 25T(n/5) + 20(n\log n)^{1.99} $

Note that $(\log n)^m=O(n^\epsilon)$ for all $m,\epsilon\in \Bbb R^+$. In plain words, all polynomials of $\log n$ grows slower asymptotically than all polynomials of $n$. Here we abuse "polynomials" to include functions like $x\to x^k$ for all $k\in\Bbb R^+$ such as $x\to x^{0.618}$ or $x\to x^{2019.46}$. This abuse of the term "polynomial" is common when we are talking about the asymptotic behavior of functions.

In particular, $(\log n)^{1.99}=O(n^{0.005})$.

Since $(n\log n)^{1.99}=n^{1.99}(\log n)^{1.99}= O(n^{1.995})=O(n^{log_525-0.005})$, you can apply the case 1 of Master theorem. $T(n)=\Theta(n^2)$.

---

If $f(n)$ is indeed smaller or larger than $n^{\log_b a}$by less than a polynomial factor, then we are running into the cases strictly between case 1 and case 2 or between case 2 and case 3. [The master theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/master-theorem/) you were reviewing cannot be applied any more.

You may look into [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/86285/91753) that handles some of those situations.

---

**Exercise.** Show that $(\log n)^m=O(n^\epsilon)$ for all $m,\epsilon\in \Bbb R^+$. (For example, $(\log n)^{10000000}=O(n^{0.000001}).$)

Comment: I would like to ask one more thing, in your comment and in the link I provided, there ϵ symbol is used and this ϵ is a real number or natural number?

Comment: I think polynomials are variables with integer exponents?

Comment: How do you find $(logn)^m$? and please tell me how do find other log exponents?

Comment: Updated. Is it clear now?

Comment: what is mathematical procedure to calculate $(log n)^{1.99}$?

Comment: @DebasisJana Please join [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95231/master-theorem-cs-110888).

Comment: I am not able to reply to answer you in the chat box. Now what you explained that's i I know. But how did you evaluate $(logn)^{1.99}$ to $n^{0.005}$? I am bit confused..

Comment: @DebasisJana please come to http://collabedit.com/wc54b